# Index values in Excel - Highest value is X, lowest is Y and all in between is divided in between X and Y

Tags: excel-formula

I need to index prices in Excel, so the highest price is 5 and the lowest is 1.
All the prices in between needs to be automatically sorted and given a value, depending on the amount of entries.

eg.

8$ -> 5.0  (Highest price = index score 5)

3$ -> 1.0  (Lowest price = index score 1)

7$ -> 2.5  (Price between the highest and lowest, gets a weighted score, depending on amount of entries in the list)

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence "Price between the highest and lowest, gets a weighted score, depending on amount of entries in the list" is very unspecific. how is the weighted score calculated? How does the amount of entries in the list impact it? Can you give a specific example so we understand why the value for `7$` is `2.5`? Is the weight depending on the position of `7$` in the sorted list of values?

On the other hand, if all you're looking for is an increasing affine function that maps values in a given range `[a,b]` to another range `[c,d]`, then there is a simple formula. In your example, `a=3$, b=8$, c=1.0, d=5.0`.

For a new value `x` in the range `[a,b]`, the corresponding value `y` in the range `[c,d]` is given by:

**`y = ( (d - c) * x + (bc - ad) ) / (b - a)`**

With your example, `(d-c)/(b-a) = (5.0-1.0)/(8$-3$) = 0.8/$` and `(bc-ad)/(b-a) = (8$*1.0-3$*5.0)/(8$-3$) = -1.4`.

Therefore **`y = (0.8/$) * x - 1.4`**.

For instance if `x = 7$`, then `y = (0.8/$) * 7$ - 1.4 = 4.4`.